# What are the gas costs for type casting or conversions?

Tags: solidity, gas, state-variable, type-casting

I frequently cast unsigned integer types (e.g. `uint8`) to signed integer types (e.g. `int24`), this requires 2 casts first to the unsigned type (e.g. `uint24`) then to the signed type (`int24`). I know I could store that variable as an `int24` to avoid this casting to begin with, but my understanding is that computation is generally cheaper than storage especially since I've bundled the `uint8` in a state struct, so in my context to read a `uint8` from storage and cast it to an `int24` would be cheaper than simply reading an `int24` from storage. Is this understanding correct and if so what would be the relative gas savings between the 2 methods?

An oversimplified example of the 2 methods:

```
// method 1
struct State {
  uint8 myNumber;
  int24 myInteger;
}

function doSomething() {
  return myInteger + int24(uint24(myNumber));
}

// method 2
struct State {
  int24 myNumber;
  int24 myInteger;
}

function doSomething() {
  return myInteger + myNumber;
}
```

Comment: I think the best answer to this would be to test your scenario. I was trying to find an answer in official Solidity documentation, but there was no word of it.

Answer (score 3):

Short version, it depends, but you can expect between 42 and 46 gas, when tested with Solidity 0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.

General thoughts - casting to int/uint is cheapest, it costs ~2 gas to cast between signed/unsigned.  There may be some conflating factors here as well, but these are the results I got testing a single function, reading a state variable and directly returning it:

```
contract TestCasting {
    int128 testValue = 123;

    function aaaa() public view returns (int) {
        return testValue;
    }
    // 2,415 uint => uint
    // 2,415 int => uint
    // 2,457 uint8 => uint
    // 2,457 uint64 => uint
    // 2,457 uint192 => uint

    // 2,459 int8 => uint
    // 2,459 int128 => uint

    // 
    // 2,459 int128 => uint128
    // 2,457 uint128 => uint128
    // 2,459 uint128 => int128
    // 2,461 int128 => int128 // WTF?

    // 
    // 2,469 int8 => int128

    // 2,459 uint8 => int
    // 2,461 int8 => int
    // 2,461 int128 => int
}
```

Final thoughts: The cost of a cast works out to about ~0.1c on mainnet, or 0.00012c on Polygon.  If you spend an hour optimizing your casts and removed 1 cast every 3 minutes, that work would require ~19 million transactions to pay for itself.

In other words, it's probably not really worth worrying about.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to find relevant documentation so tested out the gas consumption of the functions.

```js
struct State1 {
    uint8 myNumber;
    int24 myInteger;
}

struct State2 {
    int24 myNumber;
    int24 myInteger;
}

State1 state1 = State1(1, 1);
State2 state2 = State2(1, 1);

function test1() public view returns (int24) {
    return state1.myInteger + int24(uint24(state1.myNumber));
}
// gas consumed : 556

function test2() public view returns (int24) {
    return state2.myInteger + state2.myNumber;
}
// gas consumed : 564
```

We can see that even `test1` consumes less gas than `test2`. So from a transaction gas cost point of view, type conversion is better in this case.

Comment: you pay 22 more gas because the method id of test2 comes after test1..